# Signed APK cannot be installed on a device

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signed

Cannot install signed release APK on my phone and cannot upload it on Play Store.

I created a signed release APK with V1 and V2 JAR signatures check boxes checked. When I try to put the APK on my phone and install it gives:

> *App Not Installed*

I double checked and I don't have the app installed with the same package name; I removed it for all users.

After no luck, I thought of uploading it to Play Store using Test Draft, but
as soon as I upload the same signed release APK, it gives me the error:

> No JAR Signature.

I'm using Android Studio Version 3.3 and I'm dealing with a Play Store Jar Signature error (double checked V1 and V2 checkboxes and both are checked).

**Play Store error:**

[image]

Generating release APK with Android 3.3 (latest as of now) produces same error on APK installation and during the Play Store upload.

Generating signed release APK with my other system which have Android version 3.1 works fine (APK installation and Play Store upload without any errors).

It may be a fix, but still the source of the error is not found.

Comment: You should check only V2 JAR signature!

Comment: Unless you were using either V1 or V1 and V2 both in the previous apk you should only check V2.

Comment: just tried V2 alone no luck their either.

Comment: when you create a signed apk except for the first time,then you must have to provide the path to keystore of that particular application. otherwise, if you provide anyother keystore or wrong keystore path. your app in playstore end with the invalid signed apk error.

Comment: @JayMungara it is Version 1.0 there is no other version of current applicaiton on play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your APK is not signed. You can verify this locally by running the following command:

```
jarsigner -verify app.apk
```

If the app is signed (with v1 signing), it should output `jar verified.`

Are you sure that you are uploading the APK that is signed and not an old build or an intermediate artifact?

Comment: Jar is Verified.
Although this not the one Issue i am facing in_ AS 3.3_ latest Release 
Verifying the Alias on command line **keytool -list -keystore app.apk** 
Typing same key when generating Signed APK it keeps on checking for the previous Alias name in the current keystore file. 
Same procedure followed on other System with AS 3.1 just work i don't have a clue to why.

Answer (score 0):

Try using third Party Software for Signing. That fixed it for me I was having the same issue and nothing else helped. FYI you can still use the key you generated in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Check many factors on this issue.

1. add this line in your manifest.  'android:testOnly="false"'
2. add this line in your build.gradle app 'multiDexEnabled true'

After this all you have to open setting in your mobile allow from unknown source and also allow from source like from files or whatsapp from where you want to install this application.
check image for more understandings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRpDp.jpg)